# How to redirect user to paypal with parameters from c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

If I have simple form like this one bellow I can use it to redirect user to paypal to complete payment:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
    <input type="hidden" ...
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<%= someVariable %>" />
    <input type="submit" value="ok" />
</form>
```

As I have to do some actions before redirect user to paypal I need to make normal
`asp` button that will dome some actions before redirect user to paypal.
My question is how I can do this from c# code-behind?
It's important that I can pass all required hidden fields like '`custom`' from form above.

Comment: Its a little tricky, because asp.net forms did not allow other/second form to run... like this one of paypal

Comment: Actually I know that web forms are just that one form. But I also find out that if you add `<form></form><form action="...</form>` it works.

Comment: Yes you can render the `</form>` before that one, then add your parametres, but after the last form that you add, do not add other asp.net controls that make post back because the form of asp.net will be broke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traditional ASP.Net doesn't allow multiple **form** tag.

The following sample code will let you post the **form** to **PayPal** from code behind.

```
protected void BuyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string url = TestMode ? 
      "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr" : 
      "https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr";

   var builder = new StringBuilder();
   builder.Append(url);
   builder.AppendFormat("?cmd=_xclick&business={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Email));
   builder.Append("&lc=US&no_note=0&currency_code=USD");
   builder.AppendFormat("&item_name={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ItemName));
   builder.AppendFormat("&invoice={0}", TransactionId);
   builder.AppendFormat("&amount={0}", Amount);
   builder.AppendFormat("&return={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ReturnUrl));
   builder.AppendFormat("&cancel_return={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(CancelUrl));
   builder.AppendFormat("&undefined_quantity={0}", Quantity);
   builder.AppendFormat("&item_number={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ItemNumber));

   Response.Redirect(builder.ToString());
}
```

Here are more information about PayPal Standard Fields - [HTML Variables for PayPal Payments Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/)

Comment: Really just simple `Response.Redirect` :) I will accept answer after test... thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make a form dynamically and post it using C#. The below code does it -

```
 protected void Pay()
 {
    RemotePost myremotepost = new RemotePost();
    myremotepost.Url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    myremotepost.Add("business", "merchantemail@gmail.com");
    myremotepost.Add("cmd", "_xclick");
    myremotepost.Add("item_name", "Hot Sauce-12oz Bottle");
    myremotepost.Add("amount","5.95");
    myremotepost.Add("currency_code","USD");
    myremotepost.Post();
 }

public class RemotePost
{
    private System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection Inputs = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
    public string Url = "";
    public string Method = "post";
    public string FormName = "form1";

    public void Add(string name, string value)
    {
        Inputs.Add(name, value);
    }

    public void Post()
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<html><head>");
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("</head><body onload=\"document.{0}.submit()\">", FormName));
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("<form name=\"{0}\" method=\"{1}\" action=\"{2}\" >", FormName, Method, Url));
        for (int i = 0; i < Inputs.Keys.Count; i++)
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("<input name=\"{0}\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"{1}\">", Inputs.Keys[i], Inputs[Inputs.Keys[i]]));
        }
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</form>");
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</body></html>");
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

Fully tested and Working !

Answer (score -1):

You could just build a long URL and put all of that stuff on there as URL parameters.  Since you're working with C#, though, I'd recommend using the API.  In this case I'd look at [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/overview-ec/).

Comment: Which is why I recommend using the API!  Neg repping a good answer.  Good luck finding help in the future.

Comment: One more time, that's why I recommend the API!  What don't you understand about that?  I gave you the quick, simple solution, which yes, has drawbacks.  The API would be the correct way to do it.

Comment: But I know ASP.NET handles web service API's very easily.  You need to move away from basic HTML form POSTs and start working directly with API's.  You could use NVP strings and HTTP POSTs, or you could use SOAP and PayPal's WSDL.  Very secure and provides a lot more flexibility than what you're trying to do here.

Comment: I have asked how to post from code not via api. I feel that you are angry about something... I didn't down vote your answer btw.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  The API would be from code.  That response.redirect answer you're looking at looks like essentially what I said about URL parameters.  It's really just a matter of whether you're using Payments Standard vs something like Express Checkout.  EC would be the recommended method from a c# application, but if you get it working the other way and you're happy with it, that's all that matters.